# The programming logic

Tags: javascript, logic

I'm following an online Javascript course for beginners. One exercise is about Math.floor(), and the example given is:

```
get floorNum(x){
    let _x = x;
    _x = Math.floor(x);
    return _x;
}
```

My question is: why not just put "return Math.floor(x)" in the function body? Why let _x = x, and then return _x? Why not just return x directly? What's the underlying logic?
I want to learn some basic programming logic.

I tried google, but didn't find what I want. I'm an absolute beginner.

Comment: you're right, that code makes no sense at all.

Comment: You are correct, you would not normally use `floorNum` - it appears to be a derived example on how you would use `get` - though if you copy that code into a browser, it won't work, so this doesn't appear to be "pure" javascript, or is incomplete as provided here.  What's the online course?

Comment: `let _x = x; x =` can, in some languages, be a bad practice as it would require an assignment that's not needed.  As javascript is typeless, this could just be `let _x;` or would normally be `let _x = Math.floor...` - but they're probably trying to instil the "best-practice" of declaring variables separately from where they are used - then failing to do so properly.  How confusing for a beginner.

Comment: It's a course, I suppose it's trying to show you the fundamentals before showing "shorcuts". I doubt there is much more to it. You shouldn't be using code in courses for beginners as the gold standard. It's after all supposed to teach you about programming before it shows you how to improve.

Comment: With that said, `get floorNum(x)` is weird. It's a getter but getters don't receive any arguments. Essentially the `x` is always going to be `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, exactly what i was thinking. Seems like the exercise the OP was doing has been designed incorrectly

Comment: @Angus do you have a link to the online course?  Or is it a paid course?

Comment: @freedomn-m  hi there, thanks a lot! I appreciate your concern. This is the link: https://www.alchemy.com/university/courses.   (I chose the lowest level to begin with. The course is a step-by-step model, you must start from level 1 and then level 2 ..., to be honest, the quoted code is my answer to the last question of level 1, I tried many codes, and lastly, I got that one, and I passed! After I submitted the answer, I asked here by memory, and now I know I made a big mistake!

Comment: @freedomn-m The original question is "function getFloor(x){}", and the assignment is "Take the argument x and use Math.floor to turn it into an integer". Now I know there're many ways to code, some clever, some stupid. I did a stupid code, and afterwards, I figured out a clever one, which I didn't know until I read your kind answers.

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm an absolute beginner, forgive my stupid mistake. I learned a lot here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it step by step :

```
get floorNum(x){
    // Here you are duplicating the argument (supposing it's a number)
    let _x = x;
    // Here you are reassigning the previous variable, making the first line useless
    _x = Math.floor(x); 
    return _x;
}
```

As the first line is useless, your code could be refactored to this:

```
get floorNum(x){
    const _x = Math.floor(x); 
    return _x;
}
```

And as you're not doing anything with `_x` except returning it, then it can be refactored again to:

```
get floorNum(x){
    return Math.floor(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right!, there are no reason to do this 8n this example.

you can write it like this

```js
function floor(x) {
return Math.floor(x)
}
```

but keep in mind that this technique is useful when working with cloned classes, objects.

Answer (score 0):

This also works fine.

`get floorNum(x){return Math.floor(x);}`

I think they coded that way, to understand easily.
And they used the underscore ( _ ) to indicate that a variable name can start with ( _ ) sign too. Among professional programmers, use this sign as an alias for "private (hidden)" variables.

Comment: In JS/C# (at least, not all languages) the `_` *convention* means its a "private variable" that only accessible within that method/class and should not be accessed directly (eg with a private module-level variable that has a getter/setter).

Comment: In JS/C# (at least, not all languages) the _ convention means its a "private variable" that only accessible within that method/class and should not be accessed directly

Answer (score -4):

Try like this:

_x = x => Math.floor(x);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Actually in js we can declare a variable starting with _.
According to my intuition they might have used _ for just to represent the word floor.
There's no any restriction to write or declare variables in such a way.